# To list the databases and logins

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, logins

Can anyone tell me the query to list the databases and SSRS reports and different logins in a particular server ?

Answer (score 0):

**List all databases**

```
select * from sys.databases
```

**List SSRS Reports**

```
use [ReportServer]

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Catalog]
WHERE [Type] = 2
ORDER BY [Path]
```

**List all Logins**

```
select * from sys.syslogins
```

**List users having permission to reports**
from stackoverflow link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600480/ssrs-determine-report-permissions-via-reportserver-database-tables

```
    select C.UserName, D.RoleName, D.Description, E.Path, E.Name 
from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
   inner join dbo.Policies B on A.PolicyID = B.PolicyID
   inner join dbo.Users C on A.UserID = C.UserID
   inner join dbo.Roles D on A.RoleID = D.RoleID
   inner join dbo.Catalog E on A.PolicyID = E.PolicyID
order by C.UserName
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the query to get folder and report level permissions. ?